# Copy rows inside data.table based on condition

Tags: r, data.table

My sample data.table looks as follows

**Starting Data**

```
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(id = as.character(c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)),
            time = as.character(c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)),
            status = c("P", "R", "R", "R", "R", "P", "P", "P", "R", "R", "P", "P", "R", "R", "R"),
            balance = c(100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 320, 300, 250, 200, 100, 40, 34, 31, 29, 10),
            employment = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y")
)
```

The objective is to copy the information in the columns balance and employment if the status migrates from "P" to "R" by "id". I.e. I would like to use the data in the last period in which a id is "P" and overwrite the existing information for all next periods in which the id is "R".

Hence, the goal is to obtain this data.table

**Goal**

```
Y <- data.table(id = as.character(c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)),
            time = as.character(c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)),
            status =     c("P", "R", "R", "R", "R", "P", "P", "P", "R", "R", "P", "P", "R", "R", "R"),
            balance = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 320, 300, 250, 250, 250, 40, 34, 34, 34, 34),
            employment = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y")
)
```

Note that the columns time and status itselft  (and of course id) are not affected.

I have tried to use `seq_len` across id's, then set this column to zero if status is "R and search for the max value (by id) of this column to use as an indicator which row has to be copied. I'm sure there is a faster and better way to resolve this. Maybe even an one-liner.

If anything is unclear please let me know

Comment: Does all ids always start with `P`?

Comment: Yes, well it always starts with a non R letter (in this example P)

Comment: So the `by` part doesn't matter I would guess then

Comment: What should happen if somebody goes from P to R, back to P, and then to R again?

Comment: @DavidArenburg : You are right it simply has to search for the last row of P.

Comment: @Adam : That is not possible (in my example). If you are in R, you stay there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to do this is to set the desired columns to `NA`s when `status == R` and then carry the last observation forward (LOCF), since all the `id`s start with `P`, I don't think you really need to do this by `id` and hence improve performance. Here's a way

```
## Define column names you want to modify
cols <- c("balance", "employment")

## Assign `NA`s when satus == "R"
x[status == "R", (cols) := NA]

## Carry the last observation forward and update by reference
library(zoo) ## You could do this with base R too, just more writing
x[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, na.locf), .SDcols = cols]
```

Comment: `j` should be `(cols) := lapply(.SD, na.locf, na.rm=FALSE)` in that case

Comment: `by = id` probably should be included. It isn't required on provided data just because the `id` is sorted and there weren't `status=="R"` on the first entity of each `id`.

Comment: @jangorecki not sure regarding the `, na.rm=FALSE` and if you want to make sure it is ordered, probably just inserting `order(id)` in the `i`th expression will be much more efficient.

Comment: `na.rm=TRUE` will result into length of result shorter than `nrow` of data.table so also warnings and probably wrong results due to recycling. Check bigger sets, as in my answer :)

Comment: No need for `lapply`? `x[, (cols) := na.locf(.SD), .SDcols = cols]` seems to give the right result.

Comment: @Frank I think `na.locf` performs much worse on a `data.frmae`/`data.table` than on a vector. I remember benchmarking it and seeing a huge difference.

Comment: people still upvoting your answer while mine doesn't need `zoo` and is faster :(

Comment: @jangorecki are you serious?

Comment: @DavidArenburg yes, why not? just reproduce the benchmark.

Comment: @jangorecki I meant more like are seriously behaving like a crybaby regarding upvotes? I know your is a bit faster (though a second difference usually doesn't change much) but it is much more verbose and cryptic.Only a `data.table` power user can understand your code and only few will be able to modify it. Not *everything* is always about speed, especially if the improvement is so little. Not to mention that the main idea on how to approach this problem was mine, you basically just improved it.

Answer (score 6):

Adding also plain data.table solution vs zoo solution. Data.table rolling join seems to scale better.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

x = data.table(id = as.character(c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)),
               time = as.character(c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)),
               status = c("P", "R", "R", "R", "R", "P", "P", "P", "R", "R", "P", "P", "R", "R", "R"),
               balance = c(100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 320, 300, 250, 200, 100, 40, 34, 31, 29, 10),
               employment = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y")
)
y = data.table(id = as.character(c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)),
               time = as.character(c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)),
               status =     c("P", "R", "R", "R", "R", "P", "P", "P", "R", "R", "P", "P", "R", "R", "R"),
               balance = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 320, 300, 250, 250, 250, 40, 34, 34, 34, 34),
               employment = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y")
)

zoo = function(x, by = "id", cols = c("balance", "employment")){
    x[status == "R", (cols) := NA]
    x[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, na.locf, na.rm=FALSE), by = by, .SDcols = cols]
}

dt = function(x, by = "id", cols = c("balance", "employment")){
    x[, i := .I]
    x[status == "R", (cols) := NA]
    # Rdatatable/data.table#1217
    x[, (cols) := x[status != "R"][x, .SD, roll = TRUE, on = c(by,"i"), .SDcols = cols]
      ][, i := NULL]
}

all.equal(zoo(copy(x)), y, check.attributes = FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(dt(copy(x)), y, check.attributes = FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

And the benchmark.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

zoo = function(x, by = "id", cols = c("balance", "employment")){
    x[status == "R", (cols) := NA]
    x[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, na.locf, na.rm=FALSE), by = by, .SDcols = cols]
}

dt = function(x, by = "id", cols = c("balance", "employment")){
    x[, i := .I]
    x[status == "R", (cols) := NA]
    # Rdatatable/data.table#1217
    x[, (cols) := x[status != "R"][x, .SD, roll = , on = c(by,"i"), .SDcols = cols]
      ][, i := NULL]
}

data = function(N, seed = 123){
    set.seed(seed)
    data.table(id = as.character(sample(300, N, TRUE)),
               time = as.character(sample(500, N, TRUE)),
               status = sample(c("P","P","R","R","R"), N, TRUE),
               balance = runif(N, 34, 300),
               employment = sample(c("N","N","N","N","N"), N, TRUE))
}

run_n = function(N){
    # zoo
    x = data(N)
    cat(sprintf("zoo %0.e:\n", N))
    print(system.time(
        zoor <- zoo(x)
    ))
    # data.table
    x = data(N)
    cat(sprintf("data.table %0.e:\n", N))
    print(system.time(
        dtr <- dt(x)
    ))
    # equal
    isTRUE(all.equal(zoor, dtr, check.attributes = FALSE))
}

sapply(c(1e4,1e5,1e6,1e7), run_n)
#zoo 1e+04:
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.024   0.000   0.022 
#data.table 1e+04:
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.004   0.000   0.004 
#zoo 1e+05:
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.048   0.000   0.044 
#data.table 1e+05:
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.016   0.000   0.016 
#zoo 1e+06:
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.264   0.028   0.292 
#data.table 1e+06:
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.172   0.000   0.172 
#zoo 1e+07:
#    user  system elapsed 
#   2.952   0.188   3.130 
#data.table 1e+07:
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.932   0.176   2.109 
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: `x[, (cols) := .SD[1], by=cumsum(status!="R"), .SDcols=cols]` is also a non-zoo solution. I guess yours is faster, but don't really roll like that (and so don't know).

Comment: @Frank I think your solution will not produce expected results.

Comment: It certainly seems to work for the OP's case. After running it, `identical(x,Y)` is true. I cannot think of any case in which it would not work, so maybe you could elaborate..?

Comment: @Frank OP data does not reflect complexity from his description, to perform locf by group. If you would have `status=="R"` at the first position within group then it wouldn't be handled correctly.

Comment: Well, the OP noted "Yes, well it always starts with a non R letter" albeit in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This works using only `data.table`, but the run time is much slower than the `locf` option David proposed.

```
hash <- x[status == 'P', .(t = max(time)), .(i = id)]
hash[,c('b', 'e') := x[i == id & t == time, .(balance, employment)],
     .(i)]
setnames(hash, 'i', 'id')

x <- merge(x  = x,
           y  = hash,
           by = 'id')

x[status == 'R',
  `:=`(employment = e,
       balance = b)]
x[,`:=`(e = NULL,
        b = NULL,
        t = NULL)]

print(all(x==y))
```